# What will happen to a suggested edit if in the meantime, the owner gets the privilege to edit posts?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I was thinking of all the ways an approved Suggested Edit may not lead to an increase in reputation for this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1244442/suggested-edits-reputation-league?n=100). Then a thought occurred that what will happen if a user suggests an edit and before that edit is approved (or rejected), they earn the privilege to edit directly. Will that suggestion grant them 2 reputation on approval, or will that edit automatically take place giving the user no extra reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the user later earns 2,000+ reputation after suggesting the edit, the suggested edit will still be treated as one, and will still require review and approval from other users. If that is approved, the user will earn 2 reputation.

Comment: And the user will not be able to approve or reject their suggestions. Right?

Comment: @GarimanSingh Nope, the user can't review their own suggestion.